# Return Error in Web API2

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api2

I need to return error from my Web API. That means after validation. I have custom error model will send as a json.
How can I send this? Like BadRequest(Model);
IHTTPActionResult is using. 
If using HttpresponseMessage, We can pass. But in IHTTPActionResult how Can I pass custom error model with BadRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Just return an internal server error. It has an overload to return an exception with a message.

```
public IHttpActionResult YourMethod()
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch
    {
        return InternalServerError();
        //or
        return this.BadRequest(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourModel));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a custom error model. So I need to send that model as JSON